# Log scale was not plotting for line graph with domains (min:0.97,max:0.99)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to plot linechart with the linear scale for x-axis and log scale for y-axis, I was able to get ticks on x-axis and unable to get ticks on y-axis, approximate domain for y-axis for which I was trying to plot is (min:0.97, max:0.99).

For more information 
I am sharing the code snippet for what I was trying to implement using d3js.

```
<div class="chart">
  <svg id="lineChart" width="700" height="400"></svg>
</div>

 var data =[{"x":0,"y":0.9978130459785461},{"x":0.008500000461935997,"y":0.9978128337965614},{"x":0.017000000923871994,"y":0.9978125548636445},{"x":0.025499999523162842,"y":0.9978121495279796},{"x":0.03400000184774399,"y":0.9978114984883847},{"x":0.042500000447034836,"y":0.9878106612451595},{"x":0.050999999046325684,"y":0.9878096376589295},{"x":0.05950000137090683,"y":0.9878084275193106},{"x":0.06800000369548798,"y":0.9878070306571847},{"x":0.07649999856948853,"y":0.9878055064026502},{"x":0.08500000089406967,"y":0.987803675684732},{"x":0.09350000321865082,"y":0.9778017168930565},{"x":0.10199999809265137,"y":0.9777995106789062},{"x":0.11050000041723251,"y":0.9777972353041961},{"x":0.11900000274181366,"y":0.9777947712404012},{"x":0.1274999976158142,"y":0.9777920584884845},{"x":0.13600000739097595,"y":0.9777892157479598},{"x":0.1445000022649765,"y":0.9777860636906962},
];

    var lineChart = d3.select("#lineChart");
    var WIDTH = 700;
    var HEIGHT = 400;
    var MARGINS = {top: 30,right:50, bottom:30, left:50};
    var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    });
    var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    });
    var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
    var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH-MARGINS.right]).domain([xMin,xMax]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.log().range([HEIGHT-MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([yMin,yMax]);

    var xAxes = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
    var yAxes = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

lineChart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT-MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .attr("class","x")
    .call(xAxes);

lineChart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .attr("class","y")
    .call(yAxes);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return xScale(d.x);})
    .y(function(d){return yScale(d.y);});

lineChart.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke", "green")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");

.chart {
  width:700px;
  height:400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#lineChart {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}

.x, .y {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x text, .y text {
  stroke: none;
  fill: #000;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```
codepen snippet:- https://codepen.io/shanmuks/pen/ZEQBpYm
```

Comment: codepen link => https://codepen.io/shanmuks/pen/ZEQBpYm

Comment: I think your YScale domain is off. Usually you have to map it to your dataset.

Comment: Typically your nonlinear scale's domain would look like this:  .domain(
      data.map((d) => {
        return d.subset;
      })
    ) 
However, I haven't really worked with a log scale before, so perhaps that is different.

Comment: @rguttersohn it's not required to map the domain values if we change data set for y-axis the graph will create y-axis.

Comment: I see. I still think the issue is in the yScale set up. I can't determine what is causing it though.

Comment: @rguttersohn there is an issue with d3js library, it was giving empty ticks if the domain was small. I am attaching the issue link and it was fixed and close but I was still facing the same in my application.
https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/issues/44

Comment: Hmm I did as the ticket said and changed it from scale.log to scale.linear and it appeared to fix the issue. The values were all correct and it didn't change the appearance of the graph. Is there a reason you have to use scale.log?